# Hibernate delete just won't fire

Tags: java, hibernate, repository, jpa-2.0

I've ask'd this before but still have no clue what is going on...

I've read about entity needing to be cleared of relationships before deleting, and about cascade.all in parent entity, however i still dont get how is hibernate not doing anything...

```
@Transactional
public void deleteAllinRange(LocalDate a, LocalDate b) {
List<Invoice> z = invoiceRepo.selector(a,b);
    for(Invoice x : z){
        x.setOwner(null);
        invoiceRepo.delete(x);
    }
```

going into for loop z list size is 314, and there is all the entities i expect there to be.
I then tried to setOwner to null, since that is the only relationship to parent element.

After nulling owner, all the attributes in x entity are type long, string or localDate so surely there cant be any relationships to parent element?

Parent element is set of Invoices with List of invoice elements

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "owner", orphanRemoval = true)
@JsonManagedReference
private List<Invoice> invoices = new ArrayList<>();
```

java fill just run `invoiceRepo.delete(x);` x 314, but will actually do nothing at all and SQL debugging shows there is not even attempt to remove anything, noting is queried here...

Why is this happening? Why is there not any queries, no errors, no nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `setOwner` and don't save the x, then it has no effect. Also, if you have a constraint `nullable=false`, you cannot set it to null.

What do you want to do? Do you want to delete Invoices and remain the owners? Then you should remove the `orphanRemoval = true`.

Or else, if you want to remove the orphans, leave it as is and just delete the Invoices without setting the owner null. It will remove orphaned owners automatically.

If you want to manage them manually, don't set a foreign key and break the relation between them, just delete any record when you want and set fields yourself null or value.

In addition, you can also use the method `delete(Iterable iterable)` of the repository to delete multiple at once.